# Using DDP in a Chrome extension

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-extension, ddp

In the Chrome extension I am building, I would like to connect to a Meteor server from the extensions popup window, for user registration, login and

I've found a brief explanation from [Meteor Spotting](http://blog.thebakery.io/meteor-spotting-building-a-chrome-extension-using-meteor/) from 2014 that indicates that it is possible to do this using ddp.js, but the project it describes appears to have disappeared.

The current version of [ddp.js](https://github.com/mondora/ddp.js) uses `import` statements, which Chrome objects to. My understanding is that these scripts are designed for Node.js. How should I edit these scripts so that they can be used in a Chrome extension as described in the Meteor Spotting article?

Alternatively, is there any example of a bare-bones Chrome extension which connects with a bare-bones Meteor server via DPP, that I can use for inspiration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my own solution. Here is a bare-bones implementation of a call to a Meteor server from a Chrome extension:

manifest.json
    {
      "manifest_version": 2

```
, "name": "DDP Test"
, "version": "0.1"

, "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery-3.1.0.js"
    , "meteor-ddp.js"
    , "meteor.js"
    , "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

jquery-3.1.0.js can be found [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)
eddfirs meteor-ddp.js can be found [here](https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp)

meteor.js (adapted from [Meteor Spotting](http://blog.thebakery.io/meteor-spotting-building-a-chrome-extension-using-meteor/))

```
var Meteor 

;(function meteor(){
  "use strict"

  var endpoint = "ws://localhost:3000/websocket"
  // Use your own endpoint ^^^

  Meteor = {
    call : function(){
      var args = [].slice.call(arguments)
      var methodName = args.shift()
      var callback = args.pop()
      var ddp = new MeteorDdp(endpoint)
      if (!(callback instanceof Function)) {
        args.push(callback)
        callback = function (error, data) {
          console.log("Result of "+methodName+" call:", error, data)
        }
      }

      ddp.connect().done(MeteorCall)

      function MeteorCall() {
        console.log('Connected!');

        var $deferred = ddp.call(methodName, args)
        $deferred.done(function (result) {
          callback(null, result)
        })
        $deferred.fail(function (error) {
          callback(error)
        })
      }
    }
  };
})()
```

background.js

```
;(function background(){
  "use strict"

  Meteor.call("test", 1, "two", { three: [4]})
  Meteor.call("test", "using", "a", "custom", callback)

  function callback(error, result) {
    console.log("Custom callback error:", error, ", Result:", result)
  }
})()
```

---

Output in the server console when the extension is loaded:

```
I20160917-19:35:19.352(-4)? test 1 two { three: [ 4 ] }
I20160917-19:35:19.377(-4)? test using a custom
```

Output in the Inspector for the background view:

```
Connected!
meteor.js:18 Result of test call: null test method activated with arguments {"0":1,"1":"two","2":{"three":[4]}}
meteor.js:25 Connected!
background.js:8 Custom callback error: null , Result: test method activated with arguments {"0":"using","1":"a","2":"custom"}
```